# cakephp referrer after auth deny

Tags: cakephp, authentication

How do I get the page that was denied access by the Auth component using CakePHP 2.x? If I use the referer() function, it gives me the page that linked to the denied action. Here's my code:

```
public function login() {
    //get the current url of the login page (or current controller+action)
    $currentLoginUrl = "/login";

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $this->User->recursive = -1;            
        $user = $this->User->find(
            'first', 
            array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'User.username' => $this->request->data['User']['username'], 
                    'User.password' => AuthComponent::password($this->request->data['User']['password'])
                )
            )
        );

        if ($user && $this->Auth->login($user['User'])) {                   
            //if the referer page is not from login page, 
            if( $this->referer() != $currentLoginUrl  )                 
            //use $this->referer() right away
            $this->redirect($this->referer('/admin', true));  //if referer can't be read, or if its not from local server, use $this->Auth->rediret() instead                   
            else
            //if the user lands on login page first, rely on our session 
            $this->redirect( $this->Session->read('beforeLogin_referer') );
        }
        else 
            $this->Session->setFlash('Username or password is incorrect', 'default', array('class' => 'alert-danger'));         
    }

    if( $this->referer() != $currentLoginUrl  )             
    //store this value to use once user is succussfully logged in
    $this->Session->write('beforeLogin_referer', $this->referer('/admin', true) ) ;  //if referer can't be read, or if its not from local server, use $this->Auth->rediret() instead                
}
```

So basically what happens is I'm not logged in, and I'm at this url:

`'http://localhost/hotelguide/hotels/view/17/'`

and I click on a link that would take me to

`'http://localhost/hotelguide/hotels/review/17/'`

but that requires a user to be logged in, so it redirects me to the login page, which, when I debug referrer(), it gives me this:

`'http://localhost/hotelguide/hotels/view/17/'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you not using the Auth and login the CakePHP framework provides? Would cut down those 30 lines to 4. Don't fight the framework.

Comment: Because it doesn't do what I need it to. It won't refer back properly

Comment: What do you want your referrer to be in this scenario?

Comment: It should be `http://localhost/hotelguide/hotels/review/17/`

Comment: Please check my answer. If it's useful, set the answer as accepted or vote it up. Otherwise just write what's missing in the answer or what are the problems you're dealing with now and I'll try to help.

Answer (score 2):

When you use Auth component in CakePHP and try to access a restricted site, it redirects you to login page and saves the referring page in session. Session key *Auth.redirect* holds the value you're looking for - the page that you were trying to access.

Look at the [__unauthenticated()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-AuthComponent.html#__unauthenticated) method of AuthComponent. It includes the code responsible for writing session value to *Auth.redirect*. If you don't want to use AuthComponent, you can check how it is implemented in the component and write your own solution based on the method I have mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

$this->referer() will not provide you the correct referrer url for you. If you want to get referrer url just use $this->Session->read('Auth.redirect');

You can find exact url you are looking for by $this->Session->read('Auth.redirect');

$this->referer() value update every time when you reload the page.